# Does AWS API offer a feature to check if resource can be created or not?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am having an interesting problem with AWS. The project I'm working on create's set of various AWS service instances in one predetermined zone. For example, one VPC, one firewall, one S3 bucket, RDS instance..
Now if one of these fails to be created for the lack of the general available resources in the region I have to go through nasty deletion and switch to another region.

Is there something in AWS API that can tell if there is enough resources to create instance of something without actually creating it?

Comment: What are you using to provision these resources in AWS ? Terraform, CloudFormation ?

Comment: Related: https://aws.amazon.com/solutions/limit-monitor/

Comment: Nothing so sophisticated, just plain AWS API through cli.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if one of these fails to be created for the lack of the general available resources in the region I have to go through nasty deletion and switch to another region

Not a direct answer to your question (and I would have put it as a comment, but I lack reputation to comment... hint hint), but if you were to use CloudFormation, one of the very nice features of it is that if any one resource fails to create, it will roll back the entire stack.  The other nice thing about CloudFormation is it will give you consistent infrastructure across your multiple regions.  Have you explores using CloudFormation to deploy your resources.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I will definitely check CloudFormation.